# How can I update a resource string that has been changed in the UI by the user?

Tags: c#, settings

I have written a simple C# WPF project to read data into a datagrid and then output the contents of grid as a CSV. This all works fine, so far.

However, I want the file path of the export location to be changed by the user, which again I can do, and then "stored".

I have set the default location a string in resources and can access it, but I do not know how to update the resource string if the users changes it.

```
 FilePath = ExportBonusToCSV_v1.Properties.Resources.ExportPath;
            MessageBox.Show(FilePath);
```

Can this be done or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **Isolated Storage** to persist user settings.

In case that you don't know what that is, the following might help you get started:

- ["What is it?"-type article on InformIT](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=101625)
- [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy.aspx)

Comment: Thank and the link.  It looks like the right way forward for me.. I also have a database  setting's to save which could also fit in to this

Answer (score 4):

You cannot change an embedded resource value after build. That value is baked in to the assembly.

Use a config file instead.